# Animating scale using CSS - with multiple backgrounds

Tags: css, css-animations

I've been trying for days to emulate a video editing effect using CSS3 with no luck. I have two background images (one on top of the other) and want to create an animation where I scale up or zoom the image on top while leaving the background image intact.

I have been able to successfully change the position of the top image while leaving the background intact, and I can also do an animation which scales both foreground and background images at the same time.

Here's some code to make this all a bit more clear:

My HTML:

```
<section id="about-photo" class = "light-bg img-bg" style = "background-image: url({% static "assets/images/art/cocuy-foreground.png" %}), url({% static "assets/images/art/cocuy-background.jpg" %});"> 

    <div class="container inner">
        <div class="row">
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->

</section>
```

My CSS (only including webkit for sake of brevity)

```
@-webkit-keyframes hide {

  from { background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px; }   
  to { background-position: 0px 300px, 0px 0px; } 

}


@-webkit-keyframes zoom {    

    from {-webkit-transform: scale(1,1), scale(1,1) ;}  
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(2,2), scale(1,1) ;}

}



#about-photo { 

    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;   
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;  
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;   
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;   

}
```

When I apply the animation called "hide" things work fine, but when I use "zoom" nothing happens.

Any ideas/tips would be greatly appreciated!
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you actually need to use keyframes for this. You can simply use `transition` and `transform` to achieve this. I made a jsFiddle showing how you can do that. Also be aware that you want to include other vendor prefixes so your code works in all browsers.

```css
#about-photo {
  position: relative;
}
.light-bg {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: url('http://www.broomehovercraft.com.au/graphics/bht/popups/gallery-sunset-6.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.smiley {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: url('http://www.wpclipart.com/smiley/assorted_smiley/assorted_3/smiley_a_bit_angry_T.png');
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
.smiley:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
  -o-transform: scale(2);
  -ms-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<section id="about-photo" class="light-bg img-bg">

  <div class="smiley"></div>
  <!-- /.container -->

</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/augburto/44sbrooy/

The main thing to note is that on the element you wish to have a "zoom effect", you want to apply a transition so it knows that when a transform is applied to it, it will do it smoothly (if you don't have this, then it will do the action immediately.

Right now I have it so when you hover over the smiley, it will `scale` with a transform. However, you can easily change this to a class that you can apply. As long as your element has a transition, it will create that nice "zoom-in" effect. Then the actual scaling of the image can be applied to a separate class which you can apply whenever.

For more documentation on [transitions, check out MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

If you really want to use keyframes, then update your question, but in my eyes it isn't necessary in this situation.

Comment: Hi Aug,  This works perfectly! Thanks a million for the great answer.  Dennis